# Portal-container neutral method to obtain httpservletrequest from portlet request

Tags: java, servlets, portlet, jsr286

Is there a way, using only the standard oracle JSR-286 classes, to obtain the HttpServletRequest behind a portlet request? Here is the liferay-specific method

```
HttpServletRequest httpRequest =
  PortalUtil.getOriginalServletRequest(
    PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(portletRenderRequest));
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To directly answer your question, I would try using the solution from Vamshi provided [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/582363/Portals-Portlets/java/httpServletRequest-portlets-renderRequest-code). I think that solution still may be portlet container specific since I don't see any mention of this in the JSR-286 specification. I myself have only used a container specific solutions to this.

In a more general discussion I would direct you to [Why is the servlet request not available in the portlet API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826261/why-is-the-servlet-request-not-available-in-the-portlet-api) Portlets are not servlets, so make sure you're not trying to use them in that way.

Comment: In the end I couldn't find a completely neutral way to accomplish this but instead created a wrapper class to encapsulate the container-specific methods